# Как "перевернуть" файл с ног на голову?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Имеем большой файл, 1млн строк.

Как "перевернуть" файл, чтобы последняя строка стала первой, предпоследняя второй и т.д.?

Как это сделать без сторонних программ, в терминале. Ос Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`tac`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tac.1.html) - concatenate and print files in reverse.

```bsh
tac input_file > output_file
```